# What is the wrong with the syntax in this line?

Tags: mysql

> ALTER TABLE Student MODIFY(city varchar(20));

I don't understand what is wrong, it says the message ERROR: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(city varchar(20))' at line 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading the documentation you do not need the `(` and the `)` around the [column_definition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#:%7E:text=MODIFY%20%5BCOLUMN%5D%20col_name-,column_definition,-%5BFIRST%20%7C%20AFTER%20col_name)

You should use:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Student MODIFY city varchar(20) ;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/F9Qq_qWg)